# Ubunutu 20 crashes when changing screen display setting using wayland

Tags: 20.04, display, wayland

On a multi-monitor setup with ubuntu 20, all screens are working but not matching my physical display setup, then I should drag and change the display screen place in the GUI, but after applying it, the ubuntu crashes when logged in with the Wayland server so I have to reset the laptop. However, when logged in with the ubuntu server, dragging and changing is fine.
Opting for a different Nvidia driver still cannot solve the issue. I need to be logged in with Wayland for some third-party software.
This is the summary of my system:

## System Summary Report

```
    Platform : Linux
     Release : Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (focal)
      Kernel : 5.17.0-051700-generic
Architecture : CPU = 64-bit, OS = 64-bit
   Threading : NPTL 2.31
```

## Processor

```
  Processors : physical = 1, cores = 6, virtual = 12, hyperthreading = yes
      Speeds : 9x1200.000, 2x1300.000, 1x1307.955
      Models : 12xAMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics
      Caches : 12x512 KB
```

## GPU info

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
   configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
   resources: iomemory:fb0-faf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:fb00000000-fbffffffff memory:fc00000000-fc01ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:d1080000-d10fffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Cezanne
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: c6
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:58 memory:fc10000000-fc1fffffff memory:fc20000000-fc201fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d157ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick! I realized this should be done be step by step on the display screen. First, change the primary screen to the main screen (screen 1), then apply the change (if the screen goes black (press tab and right arrow and enter). Then drag (change the placement) and apply the other screens one by one.